# Does this UML diagram make sense?

Tags: java

[image]

Im new to Java and confused about the `getTestScore(int):` and `setTestScore(int,int)` methods.
I dont understand how I can use getters and setters on an attribute that has yet to be defined. Should the ULM diagram first define something like `private int testScore`;? Im sure Im overlooking something basic but Ive spent hours trying to figure it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `test` is an array. `setTestScore(i,s)` probably stores score `s` at index `i` in the `test` array and `getTestScore` retrieves the `i`th element from the `test` array.

It might have been more clear if the property was called `testScores`